# How can I implement timeout for angular2+ http request

Tags: http, angular

Here is just regular request looking like that:

```
this.people = http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
                  .map(response => response.json());
```

Is there any way to delay/timeout that?

Answer (score 42):

You can leverage the `timeout` operator of observables, as described below:

```
return this.http.get('http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON',
          { search: params })
    .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
    .timeout(2000, new Error('delay exceeded')) // <------
    .map(res => res.json().postalCodes);
```

Comment: I had to do: `.retryWhen(errors => errors.delayWhen(() => Observable.timer(1000)))` with rxjs 5.0.2. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html

Comment: Is there a way to set the timeout globally?

Comment: @Will Is there a way to set the timeout globally?

Comment: @JoeSleiman you can set timeout globally by extending the `Http` class. See this article for more details: http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, can you take a look on this link : i describe my issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650013/add-header-and-timeout-request-globally

Comment: was there any changes in doing that with a new `HttpClient` in `angular 4.3`?

Answer (score 12):

The return value of `http.get()` is an observable, not the response.
You can use it like:

```ts
getPeople() {
  return http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .timeout(2000)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}

foo() {
  this.subscription = getPeople.subscribe(data => this.people = data)
}

// to cancel manually
cancel() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

See also https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timeout.md

Comment: Excellent answer - just a note: you also need to import the timeout operator from rxjs or this wont work: import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

Comment: Hi Gunter, I have used `timeout` with no effect (meaning no delay), but when I use `delay(1000)` it works with the data being delayed for 1 sec. I have imported ` 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'` but even when I put `timeout(5000)` I get the data immediately. Does timeout do something different than to just delay the data?

Comment: Timeout completes the observable with an error when the data doesn't arrive within time. Delay delays the output of events.

Comment: How does unsubscribing from the observable cancel the http request? I don't think it does

Comment: `http.xxx()` only emits one event and then completes. There is no need to unsubscribe. You only need to unsubscribe if the observable emits an endless stream of events.

Comment: this should be `getPeople.subscribe(data => this.people = data)`, notice the fat arrow: `=>`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there a way to set the timeout globally?

Comment: You can build a custom `Http` class that extends `Http` and add custom code. AFAIK there is also a new `Http` implementation work in progress that seems to address such use cases, but I don't know details about the progress.

Comment: @rhysclay with angular5 using HttpClient for me it works even without importing the timeout operator

Answer (score 5):

If you are using RxJS version 6 and above the current syntax is this:

import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

```
getPeople(){
  return this.http.get(API_URL)
  .pipe(
      timeout(5000) //5 seconds
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

As with the new version, you must `pipe` to use the `timeout`. And to get the response you can use `map` inside. The complete code is as below.

`import { map, timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';`

```
const sub: any = this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl, body)
    .pipe(timeout(Config.SesamTimeout),
        catchError((err: any) => {
            this.handleTimeout(err);
            return of(null);
        }),
        map((v: SesamResponse) => {
            if (v) {
                const a: SearchResultGroup[] = this.convertSesamResponseToApiFileItem(v);
                return a;
            }
        }));
```

Here `Config.SesamTimeout` is the time in milliseconds.