# Add header and timeout request globally

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

i did an interceptor service to see if the error of a request is 401 (unAuthorized) to go to login page with show and hide loading globally also.
But still need to add the header globally with this service (interceptor-service) instead of add header on every request .
second i need also to add timeout(30000) if the request didn't reply a response this 30 seconds,
i tried it manually on every request it worked but i faced a issue with hideLoadding because i configure the loading also globally.
interceptor-service code:

```
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
  public loaderService: LoaderService

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
              public events: Events) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
  }


  getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (options == null) {
      options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {
      options.headers = new Headers();
    }

    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return options;
  }

  intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    this.events.publish('showLoader');
    return observable
      .catch(
        (err) => {
          if (err.status == 401) {
            this.events.publish('unAuthorizedRequest', err);
            this.events.publish('hideLoader');
            return Observable.empty();
          } else {
            this.events.publish('hideLoader');
            return Observable.throw(err);

          }
        })
      .do(
        () => {
          this.events.publish('hideLoader');
          return Observable.empty();
        },
        () => {
          this.events.publish('hideLoader');
          return Observable.empty();
        }
      );
  }
}
```

in the app component:

```
 this.events.subscribe('unAuthorizedRequest', (err) => {
      if (!_.endsWith(err.url, '/token')) {
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
      }
    });

    this.events.subscribe('showLoader', () => {
      this.numberOfLoading = this.numberOfLoading + 1;
      if(this.numberOfLoading === 1){
        this.loader = this.loaderService.presentLoading();
      }

    });

    this.events.subscribe('hideLoader', () => {
      if(this.numberOfLoading === 1){
        this.loader.dismiss();
        this.numberOfLoading = 0;
      }
      if(this.numberOfLoading > 0){
        this.numberOfLoading = this.numberOfLoading - 1;
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle timeout globally, you can leverage the `timeout` operator directly on your observable this way:

```
intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
  this.events.publish('showLoader');
  return observable
    .timeout(2000, new Error('delay exceeded')) // <-------
    .catch( ... );
}
```

Regarding adding a header globally, you can leverage your `getRequestOptionArgs` method.

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/

Comment: I got this error when trying to add new Error('delay exceeded')
Argument of type 'Error'  is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler'. Property 'now' is missing type 'Error'.
i'm using this version :   "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",

Comment: but it works fine without new Error('delay exceeded'),
hope not work as unexpected later , because i used forkJoin() and promise.all() , and it may for a reason , the timeout error not access the error function of forkjoin or promise.all because not all their parameters are only observables or only promises, in forkjoin function their parameters are observable and promises ,  but promise.their parameters only promises.