# How to set http call timeout in angularjs 4?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have seen in angularjs 4 official page (https://angular.io/guide/http) to set http call timeout but I did not find any reference.
Has anyone tried to set it up?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to timeout angular2 http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719116/how-to-timeout-angular2-http-request)

Comment: I asked for angular 4. Thank you

Comment: Angular 4, just as Angular 2, relies on RxJS. Why don't you at least read and try the answer?

Comment: var response = this.http.get(API.root + path, options).timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded')).map((res : Response)=> this.checkResponse(res));   I have this error: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using RxJS version 6 and above the current syntax is this:

```
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
getUsers() {
   return this.http.post(API_URL, {headers: Myheaders})
      .pipe(
          timeout(5000) //5 seconds
      );
}
```

Reference: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout

Answer (score 4):

There is a timeout operator:

```
getUsers() {
   return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "users", {headers: Myheaders})
         .timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded'))
         .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: var response = this.http.get(API.root + path, options).timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded')).map((res : Response)=> this.checkResponse(res)); I have this error: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

Comment: try adding import "rxjs/add/observable‌​/timeout"; to your imports. Rxjs needs to import most functions specifically.

Comment: Yes, The solution is import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; Thank you