# How to increase HTTP request timeout more than 2 minutes in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular7

I have a request that takes more than 2 minutes to prepare the data in the backend and transmit it. The angular default time out for the HTTP request observable is 2 minutes. Any idea of how to increase the default timeout?

I read and tried the proposed solution in the following links, but all of them are working if you want to set the timeout less than 2 minutes, and none of them will work for increasing the timeout!!

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout

[Can't have a timeout of over 2 minutes with this.http.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186362/cant-have-a-timeout-of-over-2-minutes-with-this-http-get)

[How to increase waiting time for HttpClient request in angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402269/how-to-increase-waiting-time-for-httpclient-request-in-angular-5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to set http call timeout in angularjs 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503400/how-to-set-http-call-timeout-in-angularjs-4)

[Default and specific request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/default-and-specific-request-timeout/45941133#45941133)

Comment: I tried set timeout as number (of seconds) and as of date, both are limited to 2 minutes

Comment: Where does the problem happen? On the dev machine? If so, are you using the [proxy config](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)?

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't get a reply from you in the comments, but I was having this exact issue on my dev machine, and maybe that's happening to you as well.

I was using the [proxy config](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server), and the proxy's default timeout is 120 seconds (2 minutes). So, if that's your case, simply define a higher value in the configuration. The timeout must be set in milliseconds (it's set to 6 minutes in the example below).

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "timeout": 360000
  }
}
```

Comment: This exactly what I have. It works now, Thanks @marcos.

Comment: Going to upvote this twice if I can. I'm not sure why the timeout setting is pretty difficult to find within the official documentation.

Comment: Looks like this is for the webpack dev server, isn't it? How can I configure it if it's not running on dev server?

Comment: This probably won't be valid for production though imo.

Comment: if I set the timeout to 1 nothing else happens indicating that it does not effect it? Because my goals is to extend the timeout as well