# Angular Set HTTP Timeout

Tags: angular, http

I was looking for a way to stop/terminate an http request if it exceeds a certain time.
So in Angular 5, is there anyway to set a timeout for an http request?

If there is a way, how can we do something, like execute some function, after a timeout?

The method listed in this question

[How can I implement timeout for angular2+ http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719116/how-to-timeout-angular2-http-request) gives an error:

> error TS2339: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Comment: @bugs read the description for the error with the possible duplicate

Answer (score 57):

Just as the comment mentioned, you need to use the [`timeout`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html) operator. However, the linked answer is a little bit outdated. Since rxjs 5.5.2 you need to use the `pipe` method with `lettable` operators. And assumming you are using the `HttpClient` to make your requests, there is no need for `map(response => response.json())`.

Like this:

```
import { timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

http.get('https://example.com')
   .pipe(
      timeout(2000),
      catchError(e => {
        // do something on a timeout
        return of(null);
      })
    )
```

Comment: so where do i get the response ?

Comment: `http.get('https://example.com').pipe(...).subscribe(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: i get an error as: `Argument of type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Object>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: You need to return an observable from `catchError`. Check out my edit. Also please upvote and/or accept my answer :)

Comment: is returning null ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168803/discussion-between-tomasz-kula-and-s-k).

Comment: what is the purpose of `return of(null)`?

Comment: I'm using `.pipe(timeout(300000), (e) => {` but it always wait only for 1 minute max.

Comment: This worked for me :)

Comment: So how to distinguish between timeout errors and http errors such as 500 error?

Comment: It’s better to use timeout with an error for second parameter. Unless you’re just throwing away all errors or never need to distinguish between them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719185/16940