# Increase timeout in Angular 2+ and ASP.NET Core WebAPI application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Angular 2+ / ASP.NET Core MVC WebAPI application I have a long running API-call from the client UI to the server. The request times out after 30 seconds. I would like to define the timeout for this specific API call either client- or server-side.

I have only found ways to configure the server timeout globally, which is not what I want, as the 30 second timeout is fine for other calls. I've also found solutions to decrease the timeout client side by piping RxJS's `timeout` operator. However, as I understand, this is not suitable for *in*creasing the timeout?

How can I set the timeout on this specific request?
Where does the 30 second default come from?

(The code doesn't actually matter, as it is a standard API controller and a standard Angular HTTP call):

```
this.http.get('api/xyz').subscribe(d => { ... });
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/angular-httpclient-default-and-specific-request-timeout

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791127/angular-set-http-timeout

Answer (score 2):

To solve the timeout issue you can use the  `timeout` from RxJs like below

Pass time in milliseconds to `timeout` operator

Here I am passing 60 seconds as timeout, so after 60 seconds if there is no response from the server then it will throw timeout error.

```
import ‘rxjs/add/operator/timeout’; 

...

this.http.get('api/xyz').timeout(60000).subscribe(d => { ... });
```

Comment: I am using post and it did not work. any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that without extending `HttpClientModule` classes, the only expected ways for interceptors to communicate with respective requests are `params` and `headers` objects.

Since timeout value is scalar, it can be safely provided as a custom header to the interceptor.

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = new InjectionToken<number>('defaultTimeout');

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) protected defaultTimeout: number) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const timeoutValue = Number(req.headers.get('timeout')) || this.defaultTimeout;

    return next.handle(req).pipe(timeout(timeoutValue));
  }
}
```

This can be configured in your app module like:

```
...
providers: [
  [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TimeoutInterceptor, multi: true }],
  [{ provide: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, useValue: 30000 }]
],  
...
```

The request is then done with custom timeout header

```
http.get(..., { headers: new HttpHeaders({ timeout: `${20000}` }) });
```