# "Connection reset by peer" - how make 3+ minute http call with angular, .net core 3.1 api in Azure Container Instance

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to upload file via API.

Built in .NET Core 3.1
using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
Hosted in Azure Container Group

In the middleware in the pipeline I can see that response is 200. But somewhere at the end of the pipeline I am getting exception in the logs.

Because of this my SPA is getting   **(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** in browser network tab.

Tried many different things like making file size to max on Kestrel.
Increasing the timeout value on Kestrel.

```
options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
```

The method body is taking total of **66seconds** when I added the stopwatch to collect the execution time before and after the method finish.

The whole api call which both accepting the uploaded 2 files and processing them before returning. The call invocation from  the SPA is taking **2 minutes 30 seconds** when checked in the chrome browser.

This issue is not happening when I directly run the api on my laptop via Visual Studio or when I run my API on my docker windows 10 desktop.

I've followed the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000027/increase-timeout-in-angular-2-and-asp-net-core-webapi-application?noredirect=1&lq=1) to increase the timeout on the client side.

Can this be because of container hosted as Azure Container Instance and not sure that timeout from it.

I tried increasing time in Angular SPA, .net core set keep alive and even RequestHeadersTimeout to more than 10 minutes. Wondering where should I increase the time.

Here is the callstack of the exception.

```
**2020-07-07 10:27:15.544 +00:00 [INF] Processing done..**
2020-07-07 10:27:15.544 +00:00 [INF] Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200
2020-07-07 10:27:15.544 +00:00 [INF] Executed action TestCast.Controllers.TestCastController.Index (TestCast) in 69124.861ms
2020-07-07 10:27:15.545 +00:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'TestCast.Controllers.TestCastController.Index (TestCast)'
2020-07-07 10:27:15.545 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" completed keep alive response.
2020-07-07 10:27:15.545 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 69129.4114ms 200
2020-07-07 10:27:15.545 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7", Request id "0HM12BT51RIQ7:00000002": started reading request body.
2020-07-07 10:27:15.546 +00:00 [INF] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7", Request id "0HM12BT51RIQ7:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
2020-07-07 10:27:15.546 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" reset.
2020-07-07 10:27:15.546 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" sending FIN because: "Connection reset by peer"
2020-07-07 10:27:15.547 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" resumed.
2020-07-07 10:27:15.547 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" request processing ended abnormally.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: Connection reset by peer
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessSends()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoSend()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.OnConsumeAsyncAwaited()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
2020-07-07 10:27:15.550 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HM12BT51RIQ7" disconnecting.
```

Here is my action with the logic to process the uploaded files removed.

```
[HttpPost("FileUpload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
{
    
    // All code is removed for brevity

    **Log.Information("Processing done..");**

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue with .net core 3.1 in Redhat Openshift

Comment: What are you trying to do? I was uploading a large file and some long operation in the same call. I break up it into two pieces. I upload the file, start asyn operation to process the file. But via other actions I keep getting the status of that long processing operation.

Comment: you got any solution for this?