# HTTP request timeout function not executing according to time passed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, https, connection

I am following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791127/angular-set-http-timeout/49791264) to implement a timeout in a http call to a remote server.

This is the calling function; if the request returns null then the alert will be put into view:

```
this.service.getAll().subscribe(response => {
      console.log("home.page: calling servuce for data...data returned is : " + response);
      if (response != null ){
        this.tests = response;
        this.searching = false; //Turn spinner off
      }else{
        //http timeout after 2000ms
        this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: "Connection Timeout",
          message: "Check your internet connection!",
          buttons: [
            {
            text: "Ok"
            }
        ]

        }).then(alert => alert.present());
```

This is the http service; if the http call times out after 10s (1000ms) null will be returned to the caller (above):

```
import { timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

    getAll(){
        //return this.http.get<[Student]>(this.url);
        console.log("student.service-59- GET ALL called..etunr null if times out after 10000ms");
        return this.http.get<[Test]>(this.url)
          .pipe(
            timeout(10000),
            catchError(e => {
              console.log("student service  GET ALL timed out, retunr null, error = ");
              return of(null);
              
            })
          )
    
      }
```

However when I test with the internet connection off the alert / prompt appears immediately  and does not appear to wait 10seconds as defined in the timeout argument.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Wrong angular tag. [angularjs] is for 1.x, [angular] is for 2+

Comment: timeout() will call the catchError function if there is no response  from server for 10s, but in your case since the internet connection is off you will get a failed status immediately, which is why you are seeing the alert without those 10s being elapsed

Comment: So is it the catchError is catching error thrown by no internet connection ? I came across a test server to simulate  a slow connection on slowwly.robertmurray.com.uk but this website doesn’t seem to be active